# Why does my cat bite only me during an argument with my husband

Tags: cats, biting

My cat tends to go after me when arguing with my spouse. He's imprinted on me and basically is my shadow. We have a tight human to kitty bond and he doesn't like anyone else. So why the bites? There hard bites too, not nibbles no way, I bleed from them! Also if I stub my toe or something that makes me say ouch really loud, he will bit me for that too and I can see he feels bad and tries to suck up afterwards.
Can someone help?

Comment: Maybe the cat is really annoyed ? Why don't you argue with your hubby a little far away from the cat?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple possible reasons for your cat's behavior:

1. It's play aggression. Cats sometimes get wound up by activity. They may interpret it as human play, and then try to join in.
2. Cats can get really irritated or agitated by intense sensory stimulation, and they tend to respond by biting, or frantically fleeing. The most common way this is presented is the cat gets petted too much by an unwary person who fails to notice the signs of irritation/agitation, like lashing the tail, twitching, and tensing up. The person then ends up getting bit. But cats can also be set off by intense visual stimulation (flashing lights at night, for example), movement, or maybe even sound.

**Why me?**

Neither of these cases are due to the cat disliking you. In the case of play aggression, their favorite person is often a particular target, because who else would you want to play with? But either way, it could also be that something about your particular habits that's setting the cat off, or you're simply the closest person because the cat likes following you around.

**How do I stop it?**

If the problem is play aggression, it may help to play with the cat more, so it's more tired and less inclined to get wound up. And both problems would be helped by trying to stay calm around the cat, with your voice at conversation level. Though in practice, it's really difficult to change how you express yourself, I know. At least in the case of arguments, you can tell when you're getting into it and shut the cat outside the room.